# How to make a regular expression that returns false if it doesn't match in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making an app, and I have some inputs, but I only want to accept numbers from 0 to 4, and they can have decimals, but only `.5`. In other words, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ..., 3.5, 4. Only these numbers should return true. However, an if statement like this would be very long, and I thought a regular expression would be far more efficient, but I have no idea how to do this.
If anyone could help me, it would be very nice.

Comment: Simple math would be far more efficient than a regexp.

Comment: Well you can start with Regex tools like [Regexper](https://www.regexpal.com/), and try constructing your regex with things like `\d` (digit)

Comment: "*an if statement like this would be very long*" `x >= 0 && x <= 4 && x % 0.5 === 0`

Comment: @VLAZ `%` works for floats in JavaScript! I didn't know that, but that'll be prone to precision issues if anything other than a negative power of two is used.

Comment: @KenY-N OK, I did cheat a little. You're right about this. However, it's still not too burdensome to check the decimal portion for other numbers.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, I didn't think about using `%`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some non-regex solutions:

## Arithmetic only

There is a little trick that can be used - [the remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) can be used with `0.5` to check if the number is divisible by `0.5`. A check can simply be - if it's greater or equal to `0`, if it's less or equal to `4` and if it's divisible by `0.5`, so it only accepts numbers that have no decimal part (essentially `.0`) or if the decimal part is `.5`.

This produces a very concise validation:

```
const check = x =>
  x >= 0 && x <= 4 && x % 0.5 === 0;
```

```js
const check = x =>
  x >= 0 && x <= 4 && x % 0.5 === 0;

test(0);
test(0.5);
test(1);
test(1.5);
test(2);
test(2.5);
test(3);
test(3.5);
test(4);

test(0.2)
test(1.25)
test(3.75)
test(4.5);


function test(num) {
  const displayNum = `[${num}]`.padEnd(6, " ");
  console.log(`${displayNum}: ${check(num)}`);
}
```

**This may not work for any divisor!** `0.5` is special as it's a power of two (2<sup>-1</sup>) so it plays nice with the floating point arithmetic. Not all numbers do that:

```js
console.log(30 % 3)
console.log(3 % 0.3)
```

## Using more than arithmetic

You can also get the decimal part by splitting the string representation of the number on `.`. This allows for easier checking of any decimal part that's not a power of two.

Here is a robust check to allow you to pass any number - whether it's as a string or not.

```
const check = input => {
  const str = String(input);
  const num = Number(input);
  const decimal = Number(str.split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return !Number.isNaN(num) //input is a valid number
    && num >= 0 // more than zero
    && num <= 4 // less than four
    && (decimal === 0 || decimal === 5) //decimal is zero or five
}
```

```js
const check = input => {
  const str = String(input);
  const num = Number(input);
  const decimal = Number(str.split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return !Number.isNaN(num)
    && num >= 0
    && num <= 4
    && (decimal === 0 || decimal === 5)
}

test(0);
test(0.5);
test(".5");
test(1);
test("1.0");
test(1.5);
test(2);
test("2.00");
test(2.5);
test(3);
test(3.5);
test("3.0000");
test(4);
test("4.");

test(0.2)
test(1.25)
test(3.75)
test(4.5);


function test(num) {
  const displayNum = `[${num}]`.padEnd(8, " ");
  console.log(`${displayNum}: ${check(num)}`);
}
```

If only numbers are expected it can be simplified to :

```
const check = num => {
  const decimal = Number(String(num).split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return !Number.isNaN(num)
    && num >= 0
    && num <= 4
    && (decimal === 0 || decimal === 5)
}
```

```js
const check = num => {
  const decimal = Number(String(num).split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return num >= 0 && num <= 4
    && (decimal === 0 || decimal === 5)
}

test(0);
test(0.5);
test(1);
test(1.5);
test(2);
test(2.5);
test(3);
test(3.5);
test(4);

test(0.2)
test(1.25)
test(3.75)
test(4.5);


function test(num) {
  const displayNum = `[${num}]`.padEnd(8, " ");
  console.log(`${displayNum}: ${check(num)}`);
}
```

And generalises to

```
const makeRangeChecker = ({min = 0, max = 100, allowedDecimals = []}) => num => {
  const decimal = Number(String(num).split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return num >= min && num <= max
    && allowedDecimals.includes(decimal);
}

const check = makeRangeChecker({min: 0, max: 4, allowedDecimals: [0, 5]});
```

```js
const makeRangeChecker = ({min = 0, max = 100, allowedDecimals = []}) => num => {
  const decimal = Number(String(num).split(".")[1]) || 0;
  
  return num >= min && num <= max
    && allowedDecimals.includes(decimal);
}

const check = makeRangeChecker({min: 0, max: 4, allowedDecimals: [0, 5]});

test(0);
test(0.5);
test(1);
test(1.5);
test(2);
test(2.5);
test(3);
test(3.5);
test(4);

test(0.2)
test(1.25)
test(3.75)
test(4.5);


function test(num) {
  const displayNum = `[${num}]`.padEnd(8, " ");
  console.log(`${displayNum}: ${check(num)}`);
}
```

## No JavaScript

If you're taking user input from the page, you can just use the normal HTML validation:

```html
<div>Enter a number and change the focus to validate:</div>
<input type="number" step="0.5" min="0" max="4">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Which solution would you recommend between the first and third one (the one that only accepts numbers)? BTW, I am taking input from a user on the page, but I am going to use js so that is the user inputs, say, 5, it just wouldn't register, and the same for the decimals.

Comment: @Joaquin I would just go with the standard HTML validation because I think it's much more universal. In general validation libraries exist and validation functionality well understood by users. There is no need to reinvent the wheel for something like numeric validation. At most, you can use an existing library which comes with more out of the box options. It's pretty much always going to be better user experience than trying to make a function that only accepts some numbers - validation will take care of messages and usability.

Answer (score 2):

As VLAZ mentioned, it would be better to use a numeric comparison to do it.

But if you are insist, you could use following regex:

```
^(?!4\.5)[0-4](?:\.[05])?$
```

I'm also allowing trailing `.0`s like `1.0` for better flexibility.

- `^`: the beginning of the string
- `(?!4\.5)`: `4.5` is not allowed
- `[0-4]`: a number from `0` to `4`
- `(?:\.[05])?`: with an optional decimal point `.0` or `.5`
- `$`: end of the string

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kTRavX/1/)